# Select Query Min and Max in one column based on other column value

Tags: sql, database, select

I have an employee table with a name, salary, HRA, DA,Status

I want to print these **salary, HRA, DA,Status** columns with only 2 records in them, the name of my highest and lowest salary,HRA,DA based on Status Column  where Active from employee.

It should look something like this:

[image]

```
SELECT 
    salary, MIN(salary), MAX(salary) AND 
    HRA, MIN(HRA), MAX(HRA) AND 
    DA, MIN(HRA), MAX(HRA) AND Where Status = 'Active'FROM employee
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do so :

```
SELECT 
     MIN(salary) salary,  MIN(HRA) HRA, MIN(DA) DA
FROM employee
Where Status = 'Active'
UNION
SELECT 
     MAX(salary),  MAX(HRA), MAX(DA)
FROM employee
Where Status = 'Active'
```

Comment: getting single row with All row NULL

Comment: then there is an issue with your data , is Status column really holding 'active' as string?